# Django Channels WebSocket Authentication with React: Stuck at Handshake

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, websocket

I'm integrating Django Channels WebSockets into my React app and hit a roadblock with user authentication during the WebSocket handshake. Despite setting up everything according to the docs, my WebSocket connection doesn't recognize authenticated users.

Here’s what my setup looks like:

**Django Channels (consumers.py):**

```py
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()
```

**React (Chat.js):**

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { w3cwebsocket as W3CWebSocket } from "websocket";

const client = new W3CWebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat/room_name/');

const Chat = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        client.onopen = () => {
            console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
        };
        client.onmessage = (message) => {
            console.log(message);
        };
    }, []);

    return <div>Chat Component</div>;
};

export default Chat;
```

I’m passing the session ID/token via the WebSocket URL, but Django doesn't authenticate the user on the WebSocket connection. I’m missing the part where I can authenticate the WebSocket request in Django Channels based on the session ID or token provided by the React app.

Has anyone faced a similar issue, or does anyone know what I might need to do differently here? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!